# Adaptive elements by height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, adaptive-design

For example I have two blocks as at the picture.

[image: Blocks]

How can I do so that elements in Block2 would have the same height as Block1?

Comment: How about a good old `<table />`?

Comment: Depending what this is being used for, yeah a table would do the job.

Comment: It was hard to remake it with table, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

**css**

```
 .container{overflow:auto;width:400px;background:green;}
    .block1, .block2{float:left;width:50%;background:red;height:300px;}
    .elem{height:40px;background:blue;width:100%}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block1">test block 1</div>
    <div class="block2">
        <div class="elem">element 1</div>
        <div class="elem">element 2</div>
        <div class="elem">element 3</div>
        test block 2
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94Xtn/